# How to plot data in descending order in mathematica?

Tags: plotting

I have some data which is in Erfc from , i would like to curve fit on a particular function given to me. But mathematical plots the data in ascending order.That is,

[image: Mathematica Plot]

But i want the plot to be

[image]

How do i do this?

Comment: Try adding `ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", None}` to your plotting function. You may also need to adjust the position of the axes origin if you want your vertical axis on the left (use eg `AxesOrigin ~> {26, 0}`.